# Detecting whether a point is above or below a slope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Is there a simple test to know if a point is above or below a line in 2 dimensional vector domain?

Comment: add one dimension, take the cross product and look at its sign

Comment: Put $x-$coordinate of point in line and compute $y$. If it comes out to be less that $y-$coordinate of point, then point is above line; if it comes equal , the point is on the line, otherwise below the line

Answer (score 34):

If the line equation is $y=ax+b$ and the coordinates of a point is $(x_0,y_0)$ then compare $y_0$ and $ax_0+b$, for example if $y_0>ax_0+b$ then the point is above the line, etc.

Comment: Good info, but I found the variable naming a bit confusing (I can barely tell a and α apart not that it really matters). Re-naming the variables, you have point p(x, y), slope m, and the equation y = mx + b. So, following his example, if the point is above the line the following statement would be true: y > mx + b.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following:

point $P(x_1,y_1)$ 

line $Ax+By+C=0$ (in general form)

We could check the value of $y$ on the line which would correspond to $x_1$. 
 This will be $y=\frac{-Ax_1-C}{B}$.

The point would then be above the line if $y_1$ is greater than $y$. Therefore, 

 $y_1-y>0$

 $y_1-\frac{-Ax_1-C}{B}>0$

 $\frac{Ax_1+By_2+C}{B}>0$

I remember being told by my professor two years ago that the signs of $Ax_1+By_1+C$ and $B$ must be the same if the point $P$ is above the line. I really did not know why. I just tried finding out after digging up my notes.